# Batch file that search in google and opens specific web site

Tags: batch-file, google-search

Is it possible to make a batch file which search a word in google and afterwords opens a specific web site?

For example when i run this script
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
iexplore http://www.google.bg/search?q=%search%+wedding photographer

It opens IE and search automatically "wedding photographer"
I want, if it is possible, automatically to "land" at specific site http://example.com

10x in advanced!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The answer to your question is, of course, yes, it's possible. But what is your specific question? What have you tried already? Where did you get stuck? Can you give a more specific example of what should be done with Google results?

Comment: Can you provide an exact example of something you would be trying to do? Do you mean search `oranges` and open the first link that appears?

Comment: @Narzard well he didn't specify only the first link. so if you gave an answer that would open whichever link, first, second, third, then obviously that would answer his question

Comment: @barlop yeah, just wanted to get deeper into what he was trying to do

Comment: I would like to open when you type oranges a specific web site, not the first, second or third...

Comment: Can you edit your question with a step by step of what you expect the batch to do?

Comment: i've did it already ;)

Comment: Define "specific site"

Answer (score 0):

There are options for doing this:

1. [Selenium browser automation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)
2. [Phantom -- Headless web browser](http://phantomjs.org/)

You could try both of them and choose one based on your task requirements and your programming experience.

Comment: can you elaborate on the difference between those two? btw another option is wget to make an http request then try something like e.g. `chrome http://www.blah.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote this powershell script up that takes a user input, searches google with chrome, tabs to the first link and then opens it. The loop can be modified to select any element on the page (changing the number 17 in this example).

Copy this into notepad and save as a .ps1, then right click on it and open it with powershell. When PS opens, it will ask for a search term. Type `oranges`

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
$userSearch = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert Search Term'
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=" + $userSearch)
Start-Sleep -s 3

For ($i=0; $i -le 17; $i++)
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}") 
    Start-Sleep -m 150
}
Start-Sleep -s 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}") 
pause
```

There is another way by using IE and more of the .net api to grab elements off the page by ID by google search results arent really conducive to that. If you were scraping data off of a specific page that had static info, it would be more ideal to use. Real flexibility comes with using Selenium though, but that takes some programming experience. You should just be able to edit this code as is and figure out how to get it to do what you want.

Edit: Pre-requisite - have chrome.

Here is another way to do it with IE. This will prompt for a search term, then open one tab that uses "I'm feeling Lucky" to go to the best page and a second tab with regular search results. Save as a .ps1.

```
$url1 = "http://www.google.com/search?q="
$url2 = "&btnI"
$userSearch = Read-Host -Prompt 'Insert Search Term'
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url1 + $userSearch + $url2);
$ie.navigate($url1 + $userSearch , 2048)
```

Comment: Something is not working right. When i runs the script in powershell, it just closes the CMD...
It doesn't stop to ask me what i should search

Comment: I will check on this when I get home and give you more solutions as well

Comment: @TihomirYordanov added another method. Try that one